# Expectation values and variance of a distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics

We have the distribution function defined for $x\geq0$ $$f(x)=Axe^{-\lambda x}$$ In terms of $\lambda$ I got $A = {\lambda}^2$. And thus got from here $$\mu = \lambda^2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-\lambda x}dx =\frac{2}{\lambda} $$ And $$\sigma^2 = \lambda^2\int_0^\infty \left(x-\frac{2}{\lambda}\right)^2xe^{-\lambda x}dx = 0$$ The variance is surely incorrect and I can't see where I have gone wrong. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to compute the integral is to rely on the formula $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2,$$ and instead calculating the second raw moment:  $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \int_{x=0}^\infty x^2 \lambda^2 x e^{-\lambda x} \, dx = \lambda^2 \int_{x=0}^\infty x^3 e^{-\lambda x} \, dx.$$  The substitution $u = \lambda x$, $du = \lambda \, dx$ then gives $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int_{u=0}^\infty u^3 e^{-u} \, du = \frac{\Gamma(3)}{\lambda^2} = \frac{6}{\lambda^2}.$$  If you wish to compute this integral using elementary methods, then tabular integration by parts will suffice:  $$\int u^3 e^{-u} \, du = e^{-u}(-u^3 - 3u^2 - 6u - 6) + C.$$  Then we find that the variance is $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \frac{6}{\lambda^2} - \left(\frac{2}{\lambda}\right)^2.$$

For a proof of the variance formula, we simply exploit the linearity of expectation:  Since $\mu = \operatorname{E}[X]$, we have  $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[(X-\mu)^2] = \operatorname{E}[X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - 2\mu \operatorname{E}[X] + \mu^2 = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2.$$

Comment: Many thanks for this! Definitely a much easier route to take!